# Alguien puede explicarme estas líneas de código

Tags: javascript, jquery

estoy atascado con mi proyecto. encontré la solucion pero no entiendo el codigo para poder modificar de acuerdo a lo q necesite.

Esta línea entiendo que busca en uno de los td de la vista y estira el valor
pero que hace el eq(5)? esta línea está en una función fuera del código principal

```
Number($(this).find("td:eq(5)").text());
```

También tengo dificultades con estos códigos

```
precio = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(2)").text();

$(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(5)").children("p").text(importe);

$(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(5)").children("input").val(importe);
```

Comment: Eso no es PHP, eso es jQuery (algo similar a JavaScript, en el frontend).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Básicamente, :eq() es un selector por indices, osea si tienes 5 td, sus indices irían del 0 al 4.

Este selector, junto con el indice te van ayudar a manipular un td en particular. Por ejemplo: imaginemos que tenemos este codigo en un archivo html ya cargado con jQuery:

```
<body>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>a</th> <th>b</th> <th>c</th> <th>d</th> <th>e</th>
        </thead>
       <tbody>
            <tr class="uno">
                <td> uno </td> <td> dos </td> <td> tres </td> <td> cuatro </td> <td> cinco </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {

        //  obtengo el valor del 3er td(su indice seria el 2)
        var valor = $('.uno').find('td:eq(2)').text();

        //  lo imprimo
        console.log(valor); // valor impreso: tres
    });

</script>

</body>
```

También existen otros selectores. Te dejo este [enlace](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) para mas información

Respecto a las demás lineas de código de tu ejemplo:

Teniendo en cuenta que estas trabajando con cierto valor, esta linea de código va a explicar prácticamente todo lo demás:

```
precio = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(2)").text();
```

Esta linea quiere decir que en la variable precio se va almacenar un valor. Este valor, partiendo del elemento con el que estés trabajando

```
$(this)
```

va a buscar a su padre tr

```
.closest("tr")
```

luego dentro de este tr va a buscar al 3er td

```
.find("td:eq(2)")
```

para luego tomar su valor

```
.text() //  este es el valor que se le asigna a la variable precio
```

Espero que con esta linea se entiendan todas las demás.

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, entendi perfecto.. muy amable.. saludos!!